# Comparing the performance of two algorithms with Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have two algorithms `A` and `B` which have to compute a solution to some problem. Each solution is given some objective value which indicates the quality of the solution. I need to perform a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test to test whether there is any evidence that these two algorithms perform statistically significantly different from one another.

I have performed 12 trials of each algorithm and tabulated the objective values from solutions found during each trial. A smaller objective value is better.

```
 A   B
878 890
872 888
865 879
877 874
872 870
890 886
873 871
887 879
868 873
888 882
878 881
```

I am confused about a few details of performing this test.

- Should I do a one-tailed or two-tailed test?
- I'm not sure what my null hypothesis is. What should it be, given I want to find out whether algorithm `A` and `B` perform significantly different from one another?
- If $\ p$-value $> 0.05$, what does this mean?
- If $\ p$-value $< 0.05$, what does this mean?

Comment: Is this homework?  Whether or not it is, it seems to me that the "self-study" flag would be appropriate...

Comment: 1. There are many questions that relate to interpreting p-values already on site; please try a site-search (but in any case, you should begin with basic resources that are easy to find with an internet search like the wikipedia page on p-value). 2. "Should I do a one-tailed or two-tailed test?" ... this is not a question for us to guess at; you need to clarify your question enough that it's clear whether you're after only one direction of difference or whether a difference in either direction is relevant to you. It doesn't look form what you wrote like you want a one-tailed test

Comment: 3. Note that hypotheses are about populations, not samples, and the word "significantly" (or variations on it) don't belong in them.